# Lowering Firefox sandbox settings to enable use of Sandboxie

Tags: firefox, sandbox

As discussed on the [official forum](https://forums.sandboxie.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=133401#p133401), to use Firefox 60+ with Sandboxie, Firefox's `security.sandbox.content.level` needs to be lowered to level 2.

Now my concern is that the lowered sandbox content level actually has a negative impact on the security.

For instance, Firefox with the default `security.sandbox.content.level` of 5 would be a more secure sandbox as Firefox with `security.sandbox.content.level` level 2 in a Sandboxie sandbox.

Does anyone happen to have some insight on which sandboxing technology should be preferred?

Comment: Unfortunately, both sandbox systems are notoriously bad, although I don't know enough about Sandboxie itself to write an appropriate answer.

Comment: @forest Interesting. Do you have any resources for me to read into that? I haven't heard anything bad of either sandbox.

Comment: It's not common enough knowledge for there to be easy-to-understand writeups about it. I recall there are some ways to bypass Sandboxie network protections using SMB (this is anecdotal, combined with various exploit developers who work on Windows that I know talking badly about it), and Firefox's security in general is not that great (read the code, check their seccomp filters, read some Phrack papers or whitepapers on how bad the security is, etc).

Comment: @forest I don't mind technical write-ups. I use Sandboxie a lot and haven't come across any papers. A quick google led med to https://bromiumlabs.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/application_sandboxes_a_pen_tester_s_perspective2.pdf (2013). Do you happen to have any recent resources on the topic?

Comment: All I can give is resources explaining how bad Firefox's security is, even with the sandbox. For example [OR'LYEH? The Shadow over Firefox](http://www.phrack.org/issues/69/14.html). There are also some rants by the Grugq on the security issues with Firefox, especially ESR versions. Or you can see how primitive [their hardening roadmap](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Sandbox/Hardening) is compared to the relevant ones from Chrome/Chromium. The price of 0days for Firefox is also significantly lower than for any other browser. But again, I don't know enough about Sandboxie to answer.

Comment: A common rule of thumb is that "portable" sandboxes that claim to work with nearly any program are garbage since they necessarily cannot be very fine-grained. This applies to Windows just as it does to other operating systems. That's at least a heuristic pointing to Sandboxie not being ideal.

Comment: @forest Thank you for your insight. I've gotta look into that topic more.